# Are there any cheats in the game "Mojo!"?

Tags: cheats, mojo

Are there any cheats in the game [Mojo!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojo!)?

Answer (score 1):

A google for 'Mojo! cheats' comes up with the following unlockables:

> Bonus Balls - Unlock all Bonus Infusors on any
> world level
>
> Mini-Golf - Complete single player mode

This is from numerous sites such as IGN and GameFAQs, (and they have no mentions of other cheats).

Comment: Yeah, those are actually straight from the Mojo! manual. =)